# Modify a URL helper for a path?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I have the following piece of code that I'm trying to fit into some generated scaffolding

```
= form_for(@event, :url => group_event_path(@event.group_id, @event) ) do |f|
```

As you can see, I've defined a nested resource route that looks like this

```
resources :groups do
  resources :events
end
```

Now back to the form_for line above.  The default Rails scaffolding uses code similar to above to generate _form, which is used in #new and #edit.  The issue this presents to me is that form_for has to submit to these two paths

- CREATE: group_events_path(@event.group_id)
- UPDATE: group_event_path(@event.group_id, @event)

Is there a way for me to simplify this by modifying how the group_event(s)_path helpers work?

Answer (score 0):

If you use the polymorphic `form_for` syntax, this will fix it:

```
= form_for([@group, @event]) do |f|
```

Now if that `@event` object is persisted in the database then it will use the `update` route, and if it's not then it will use the `create` route.

You can do the same thing with the normal `form_for` call:

```
 = form_for(@event) do |f|
```

There's absolutely no reason to specify the `:url` option other than to customize the URL to be something different from what Rails infers.

Comment: The first approach occurred to me, but it seemed like overkill to do a second database lookup just for this one line.  I guess that's premature optimization.  Ideally I'd like to map the second approach to just build the path by looking at `@event.group_id`, throwing an exception when it's nil